# Yii Property "User.hasErrors" is not defined

Tags: php, yii, model

I want to check if has error my model like this

```
$mo=new User();
    if($mo->hasErrors){
        echo "ERROR";
    }
```

but error **Property "User.hasErrors" is not defined** occurs. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does your class have a function called **hasErrors** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CModel has no property named `hasErrors`. it is a method, not property.
replace it with `hasErrors()` like below:

```
if($mo->hasErrors()){
    //error
}
```